# Matrix preserving almost Pythagorean triples

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

The following matrix is known to generate Pythagorean triples given an initial solution $(x,y,z) $ by recursive matrix multiplication.

$$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$$

I multiplied $H$ by the column vector of the an almost Pythagorean triple $(x,y,z) = (4,7,8)$  satisfying $x^2+ y^2 = z^2 + 1$ and it also generated another solution.

My question is on why does this work in this case and are there other matrices that has this property?

Comment: This matrix and two others are known to generate all primitive triples. The matrix preserves the form $a^2+b^2-c^2,$ so would do as you say with "near triples".

Comment: So, if I have found a triple $(a,b,c)$ such that $a^2+ b^2 = c^2 \pm n$, the matrix product of $H$ with the column vector $X = [a,b,c]$, will also satisfy the given equation since $a^2 + b^2 -c^2 = \pm n$?

Comment: numb.. Yes, with the same value of $\pm n$ and the same sign. That is what "preserves the form" is saying. By the way the two other matrices mentioned are obtained from the one you displayed by 1) change signs on column 1 and 2) change signs on column 2. Then starting from the transpose of $(3,4,5)$ one reaches every primitive triple by applying the three matrices in some order [can just keep doing one, no need to use them all]. One can make a tree which has three branches from each node.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples#:~:text=Pythagorean%20triples%20by%20use%20of%20matrices%20and%20linear%20transformations,-Main%20article%3A%20Tree&text=Let%20%5Ba%2C%20b%2C%20c,matrices%20A%2C%20B%2C%20C.

Comment: Are there other matrices that preserve the form $a^2+b^2 -c^2$ other than the 3 matrices?

Comment: Well one could form products of several of the ones already described and get infinitely many more which preserve the form. I don't know if this product process gives them all.

Comment: For Pythagorean 4-tuples or higher you may be interested in the following. https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-109-01/S0002-9939-1990-1000148-0/S0002-9939-1990-1000148-0.pdf

Comment: You have found a matrix which is used in generating part of a [Tree of primitive Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples) in which a seed triple can yield 3 more triples which, in turn can be seed triples.